# build root string in treeview with parents()

Tags: jquery, html, treeview, parent

I would like to build a root based on the selection but I can not intercept the names before the selected folder. How can I do?

A piece of html code:

```
<li class="folder">
                                        <span class="fa fa-plus dark-green-font left-margin sub-sub-folder-margin navigation font-padding"></span>
                                        <div class="selected-folder">
                                            <span class="fa fa-folder dark-green-font left-margin font-padding"></span>
                                            <span class="dark-green-font left-margin text-margin-top font font-padding">Senza Certificato Contro Doppie Imposizioni</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul class="toggle-folder no-padding tw-font-size">
                                            <li class="folder">
                                                <span class="fa fa-plus dark-green-font left-margin sub-sub-sub-folder-margin navigation font-padding"></span>
                                                <div class="selected-folder">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-folder dark-green-font left-margin font-padding"></span>
                                                    <span class="dark-green-font left-margin text-margin-top font font-padding">Senza rimborso spese</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <ul class="toggle-folder no-padding tw-font-size">
                                                    @if (ViewBag.N_E_SCC_CR != null)
                                                    {
                                                        foreach (var i in ViewBag.N_E_SCC_CR)
                                                        {
                                                            <li class="folder">
                                                                <span class="fa fa-plus dark-green-font left-margin sub-sub-sub-sub-folder-margin navigation font-padding"></span>
                                                                <div class="selected-folder">
                                                                    <span class="fa fa-folder dark-green-font left-margin font-padding"></span>
                                                                    <span class="dark-green-font left-margin text-margin-top font font-padding">@i</span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </li>
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                </ul>
```

and this is my jquery test:

```
$(".toggle-folder > li span.font").click(function () {
    $(".toggle-folder > li > div > span.font").removeClass("active-folder");
    $(this).addClass("active-folder");

    var selected = $(this).parents().text();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "***" + "?folder=" + selected,
        dataType: 'HTML',
        success: function () {
            alert(selected);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Errore");
        }
    });
});
```

Thank's in advance.

**EDIT**

I have to get every @i text for build a root, the result must be, for example: span1/span2/span3 if i click on span3, if i click on span2 the result must be span1/span2. I don't have any problem to construct this in javascript or jQuery but i have some problem to get the text of previus span for build root.

Comment: For the record, I think `.parents().text()` is going to give you a serious issue... Possibly you might use `.parent().text()`, but I'm not sure exactly what it is expecting, or expected to do.

Comment: I have to get every @i text for build a root, the result must be, for example: span1/span2/span3 if i click on span3, if i click on span2 the result must be span1/span2. I don't have any problem to construct this in javascript or jQuery but i have some problem to get the text of previus span for build root.